# change textview value in fragment with data from adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

Hello I have a `cartFragment` with `RecyclerView` which is generated by by an adapter class.

In the adapter when when each card view is created a total value is calculated. In the end I want to pass this total value to a `tvCartTotal` `Textview` in the `cartFragment`.

I was able to get this done by creating a method in the `cartFragment` and calling the method `setTvCartTotal()` from the Adapter and returning the total value to the Fragment.

But the only way I was able to set the `TextView` was by putting the `TextView` in static field. I know this causes memory leaks but can't think of a better solution. Any Help? I also added the code.

Thanks!

**ShoppingCart Fragment:**

```
public class ShoppingCartFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<ShoppingCart> shoppingcartList = new ArrayList<>();
private static TextView tvCartTotal;
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String TAG = "ShoppingFrag";

public ShoppingCartFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shopping_cart, container, false);
    RecyclerView rvShoppingCart = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rvShoppingCart);
    rvShoppingCart.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rvShoppingCart.setLayoutManager(manager);
    ShoppingCartAdapter shoppingCartAdapter = new ShoppingCartAdapter(getActivity());
    rvShoppingCart.setAdapter(shoppingCartAdapter);
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    shoppingcartList = db.getAllShoppingCart();
    shoppingCartAdapter.setshoppingcartList(shoppingcartList);
    tvCartTotal = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvCartTotal);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    shoppingcartList.clear();        
}

public void setTvCartTotal(String total) {
    //TextView tvCartTotal = TextView.findViewById(R.id.tvCartTotal);
    tvCartTotal.setText(total);
    Log.d("ShoppingCartFrag: ",total);
}
}
```

adapter:

```
public class ShoppingCartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoppingCartAdapter.ShoppingCartViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<ShoppingCart> shoppingcartList = new ArrayList<>();
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;
private double cartTotal=0;

public ShoppingCartAdapter(Context context){
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;        
}

public void setshoppingcartList(ArrayList<ShoppingCart> newList){
    shoppingcartList = new ArrayList<>();
    shoppingcartList.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public ShoppingCartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.shoppingcart_cardview, parent, false);
    ShoppingCartViewHolder shoppingCartViewHolder = new ShoppingCartViewHolder(view);
    return shoppingCartViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ShoppingCartViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ShoppingCart shoppingCart = shoppingcartList.get(position);
    holder.tvProductName.setText(shoppingCart.getProductName());
    final double price = shoppingCart.getPrice();
    holder.tvProductWholesalePrice.setText(Double.toString(price));
    final double total = shoppingCart.getTotal();
    holder.tvProductTotalSale.setText(Double.toString(total));
    final int quantity = shoppingCart.getQuantity();
    holder.etProductQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(quantity));

    cartTotal = cartTotal + total;
    ShoppingCartFragment shoppingCartFragment = new ShoppingCartFragment();
    shoppingCartFragment.setTvCartTotal("$" + String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", cartTotal)));

    TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            final int q = Integer.valueOf(holder.etProductQuantity.getText().toString());
            final double total = price * q;
            cartTotal = cartTotal - total;                
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            int q = Integer.valueOf(holder.etProductQuantity.getText().toString());
            final double total = price * q;
            holder.tvProductTotalSale.setText(Double.toString(total));
            cartTotal = cartTotal + total;
            ShoppingCartFragment shoppingCartFragment = new ShoppingCartFragment();
            shoppingCartFragment.setTvCartTotal("$" + String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", cartTotal)));
        }
    };
    holder.etProductQuantity.addTextChangedListener(watcher);                
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return shoppingcartList.size();
}

static class ShoppingCartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvProductName;
    private TextView tvProductWholesalePrice;
    private TextView tvProductTotalSale;
    private EditText etProductQuantity;

    public ShoppingCartViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvProductName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
        tvProductWholesalePrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductWholesalePrice);
        tvProductTotalSale = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductTotalSale);
        etProductQuantity = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.etProductQuantity);            
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cart should be a singleton object in your application or should be stored in a database. You can solve a lot of problems that way.

Then the View(in your case the TextView in your RV) will update the Singleton Cart and refresh itself.

Otherwise follow MVP and pass the presenter in the adapter. Under some circumstances and with the appropriate implementation it is acceptable, but this is a whole different conversation.

Comment: Thank you for the comments @Chris the cart is already being retrieved from a  database. 
The Total changes because when viewing the cart the user can change the item quantities and if this happens The TextWatcher updates the itemTotal and cartTotal which then need to updates the cartTotal TextView.  The cartTotal TextView is seperate from the RecyclerView.

Comment: The adapter contains the latest version of your cart. Create a method in your adapter that returns the cartTotal, and call this method from your fragment in order to refresh your View. The question you need to answer now is how to trigger this refresh, a possible solutions that i can think in the limited time i have now is eventbus.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know eventbus did the trick didn't know about it but I love it now.